# How to give dynamic file name in JQuery datatables for PDF File?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to find a perfect example in which I can see how to set the filename dynamically for my PDF file in datatables. I am using `datatables` version 1.10.0 and `tabletools` version 2.2.4.

Comment: what version of `dataTables` and `tableTools`?

Comment: @JAG just updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sTitle` property of tableTools configs

```
var fileName = (function() {
    //run your logic to generate dynamic file name;
    return "computedFileName";
})();
```

then

```
tableTools: {
    "aButtons": [
        {
            "sExtends": "pdf",
            "sTitle": fileName 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how is it dynamic ?

Comment: i have updated my answer, it cant get any dynamic than that, since it only accepts `string` as file name in configs.

Comment: It's not solving my purpose but it's one of the approach. +1